# Non-square modulo 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a little confused by a (seemingly) elementary claim made in a paper:
Let $n$ be a non-square in $\mathbb{F}_9$.  Then $n^4 \equiv -1 \mod 9$.
The squares modulo $9$ are $0 , 1 ,4 , 7$, and if I'm doing my calculations correctly, then the quartics mod $9$ are also $0 , 1 , 4 , 7$, no one of which is $\equiv -1 \mod 9$.  What is my error?

Comment: **Hint** $\ \Bbb F_9$ is a field with $\,9\,$ elements, not the integers mod $\,9.\ \ $

Comment: Haha of course!  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every non zero element of $\Bbb F_9$ has and order that divides $8$. Therefore it is a root of
$$X^8-1=(X^4+1)(X^4-1)$$
A square element $y=x^2$ is a root of $X^4-1$, since $(x^2)^4=1$. Therefore, a non square element must be a root of $X^4+1$.